# AT cmd response with pySerial

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I am getting "AT" as response to this code instead of "OK". Why is this?

```
import serial

class Send_Rcv():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

    def SendCommand(self,command):
        self.ser.write(command.encode())

    def ReadLine(self):
        data = self.ser.readline()
        print data

at_cmd = Send_Rcv()
at_cmd.SendCommand('AT')
at_cmd.ReadLine()
```

Comment: You may need to send a couple more until the modem responds correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modems have echo turned on by default. They echo back the characters you have sent along the wire, so that users typing on a terminal can see what they are doing.

Because you are calling readline() once, you are seeing the echo, but not the command response. Try a calling readline again to see the response.

Echo can normally be disabled by sending the command **E0** to the modem.